# Need help styling the hover states for a horizontal menu in Wordpress where each side has a unique shape

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm building a horizontal menu in Wordpress where each menu item features a shape on both the left and right sides. The menu itself was easy enough to build and is styled as a ul with li elements. The problem I'm having is with the hover states. I'm just not sure how to style them.

Since I can't post images here, I'll link to screenshots of how the menu should look. To start, here's the menu in its standard state. Note that each li has a custom shape on both sides:

[Standard State](http://reviewyourproject.com/menu/standard.png)

And here's a sample mouseover. As you can see, the hover color fills the entire shape:

[Hover State](http://reviewyourproject.com/menu/hover.png)

That seems to be the sticking point. I can get the hover state to work on the left or right side using a background image, but not both. Even targeting each li with a unique style and unique background (which I'd rather not do) doesn't work since there's no easy way to display the li's in such a away to give the illusion of it being one shape. Likewise dividers don't seem to be the answer either since I can't figure out how to trigger hover states on them.

Anyone have any ideas? I guess I'm hoping that I'm overlooking something simple or obvious. To be clear I need this to work with Wordpress, preferably via the built in menuing system.

Comment: can you provide code for what you have until now please? :)

Comment: Sure thing. Here's a link to the CSS for the main menu. It might be a little rough around the edges since I've edited it so many times. [link](http://reviewyourproject.com/menu/nav.css)

Comment: the menu itself is generated using the following code: in Wordpress `<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'main-menu', 'theme_location' => 'Masthead' ) ); ?>`

Comment: The above approach, by the way, creates a hover state that looks like this: [link](http://reviewyourproject.com/menu/wrong.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a more appropiate solution would be one without background-images. And you could use instead before and after elements, and some tricks with borders so you obtain triangles.
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4LLGV/) is a basic working example from which you could start.

```
ul{list-style-type:none;}
li{float:left; line-height:30px; font-size:25px; padding:0 10px; background: gray; margin:0 7px; position:relative;}
li:before{content:''; width:0px; height:0px; position:absolute; 
    left: -10px; top:0px; border:solid; border-color:gray transparent gray transparent; border-width:15px 0px 15px 10px;}
li:after{content:''; width:0px; height:0px; position:absolute; 
    right: -10px; top:0px; border:solid; border-color: transparent transparent transparent gray; border-width:15px 0px 15px 10px;}

li:hover{background:blue;}
li:hover:before{border-color:blue transparent blue transparent;}
li:hover:after{border-color:transparent transparent transparent blue;}
```

Comment: Wonderful. I thought about using before and after elements but had no idea you could do that with the borders. That said, your sample code gets me really close except that it relies upon transparency to create the border shape and, unfortunately, the container for the navigation shares the same background color as the li elements. This gives the appearance of arrows sitting within a bar. This is how the full menu bar looks in the mockup: [link](http://reviewyourproject.com/menu/sample.png)

Comment: So when I modify your code and apply it to my menu, I either get [this](http://reviewyourproject.com/menu/broken.png) or, if I remove the container background color, [this](http://reviewyourproject.com/menu/close.png). I tried swapping the border colors to a combination of white and or gray but I can't figure out exactly how you're creating the border shape.

Comment: Got it. I styled the opening li element as well as the last one (since they'll never change anyway) and removed the first and last arrows. Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: I'm glad that it helped :)
Good luck with your work!